# how to use adodb to write sql queries to select data that is longer than 255 characters

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I am using ADODB connection to write SQL statements to extract data in excel vba.

My problem is that I have a cell where it contains a string longer than 255 characters.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to continue to use ADODB connection to select data that has longer than 255 characters

This is the function i used.

```vb
Public Function QueryRead(sqlArg As String) As Dictionary

    Dim pConnection As ADODB.Connection
    Set pConnection = New ADODB.Connection

    With pConnection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
        ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    '.Provider = "MSDASQL"
    '.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
    "DBQ=" & App.Path & "\ExcelSrc.xls; "
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With

    Dim pMap As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim sql As String
    sql = sqlArg

    Dim resultSet As New Dictionary

    pMap.Open sql, pConnection
    If pMap.RecordCount > 0 Then

        Dim record As Variant

        Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0

        Do Until pMap.EOF

            Dim resultRecord As Dictionary

            Set resultRecord = New Dictionary

            For Each record In pMap.fields

                resultRecord.Add record.Name, record.value
            Next
            Dim index As String
            index = CStr(counter)
            resultSet.Add index, resultRecord
            counter = counter + 1
            pMap.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If

    pMap.Close
    pConnection.Close

    Set QueryRead = resultSet

End Function
```

This is how i call it

```vb
Set resultSet = model.QueryRead("SELECT * FROM [Database$] WHERE [Level] = 2 AND [Item_No] = '" & itemNo & "'")
```

My worksheet is called Database and it has columns such as Level and Item_No.

One of the cells under the column Formula has string longer than 255 characters.

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

I want to emphasize that

a) it is the individual field data extracted out that exceeds the 255 char limit. meaning to say, the * in the "SELECT * FROM "

b) it is NOT my input parameters that exceed 255 characters

c) it is NOT my query string that exceeds 255 characters

Comment: Try to use `ADODB.Command` and data binding (`Command.Parameters.Append Command.CreateParameter(text_index,enum_type,enum_direction,size,value)`).

Comment: Could you give me a clearer picture with an answer? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the Excel 2003 and earlier connection string, this [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189897/EN-US) applies. If there aren't any values longer than 255 characters in the first 8 rows of your data then all values will be truncated to 255 characters.

A simple workaround may be to ensure that the first data row on the worksheet always contains a value longer than 255 characters - either a dummy row which you later discard or a real data value which you ensure ends up in that row.

You can adjust the number of rows scanned up to 16 but this doesn't really solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `ADODB.Command` and thus data binding to overcome this and avoid unexpected SQL injection.

You'll have to modify your function to use this, so I'm only showing you a demo-like example:

```vb
Dim cmd AS ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.AcitveConnection = pConnection
cmd.Prepared = True
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Database$] WHERE [Level]=2 AND [Item_No]=?"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("item_no",adVarChar,adParamInput,512,itemNo)

Dim pMap as ADODB.Recordset
Set pMap = New ADODB.RecordSet

pMap.open cmd
If pMap.RecordCount > 0 Then
'do stuffs...
```

You can [check MSDN for detailed information about `CreateParameter` and its parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677209%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Not tested with Excel table, but I once used this method in Classic-ASP for Oracle for a few months, so it should work for you with some tweak.

One downside of this method is you can't just pass one SQL statement as function argument. You may have to accept at least two arguments, with one for SQL statement, and another (maybe a Dictionary object) for the waiting-to-bind data.

Comment: I will try out this method when I have the time. may take a while for me to come back to this though.

Comment: @kimsia Alright, your later edit clarify the question. Then this method may not solves your problem, since I previously thought it's your SQL statement that exceed the limit.